# How can I set color highlighter for SCSS variables?

Tags: css, sass, webstorm, background-color

I want to use its value as background in SCSS but it is not working. I tried color highlighter plugin and also checked settings for it but it is only working with hex code, rgb, rgba and name of color but not working with SCSS variable in WebStorm 2020.2

Sorry for my bad English.

What I see right now:
[image: here it is shown in image 1]

What I want to have:
[image: i want its background highlighted like in image2]

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to have a lighter version from another color, right?

Comment: no i want that $color-primary-light variable gets backgorun like shown in second image. i mean when i use a color wariable i want to see which color it is as its background. color highlighter plugin working perfect with vs code but it isnot working with webstorm

Comment: I see, no clue honestly

Comment: I think the issue here is that when typing a color value directly, the color itself is set as the background color in the IDE. When typing an SCSS variable, however, the text is not highlighted at all. Probably a bug in your IDE/plugin, or it/they are missing this functionality.

Comment: yes. actually plugin is not working with webstorm but we have that plugin in webstorms plugin store)). they gave this functinality in settings but it is not working with variables only working with direct values of colors

Answer (score 0):

For variables it is available as **color boxes in the gutter area only** for the moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14338 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Comment: P.S. For reference purposes: the same question on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009634300-How-can-i-highlight-color-variable-of-scss-as-background-

Comment: thanx a lot dude they are both my question)

Answer (score 0):

just point out to the SCSS variables file where your color variable definitions lay at.

For instance:
@import "../abstracts/variables";

Once you include this reference at the head of each SCSS file you create, your color highlight extension installed in vScode would paint them just as in your variables folder.